# How to join 2 Point3f arrays together?

Tags: java, graphics, java-3d

How can I join 2 Point3f arrays together?

I have tried this but it returns null pointer exception :(

```
private Point3f[] combineRings(Point3f[] a, Point3f[] b){
    int size = a.length+b.length;
    System.out.println("Size = "+size);
    Point3f[] c = new Point3f[size];
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < size; i+=2, j++){

        c[i].x = a[j].getX();
        c[i].y = a[j].getY();
        c[i].z = a[j].getZ();

        c[i+1].x = b[j].getX();
        c[i+1].y = b[j].getY();
        c[i+1].z = b[j].getZ();

        // Debugging
        System.out.println(i+"\t"+j+"\t"+c[i]+"\t"+a[j]+"\t"+c[i++]+"\t"+b[j]);
    }
    return c;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array is empty until you put objects into it. Your code assumes that you can assign to `c[i].x` immediately, but as there's no object in `c[i]`, you get a `NullPointerException`.

I don't know if you want to copy the objects in the arrays into new objects, or if you just want to copy the *references* so both arrays point to the same objects.  The second one is easy:

```
System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, a.length);
System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, a.length, b.length);
```

If it's the first one, it'd be much simpler to use the `Point3f` copy constructor:

```
for (int i=0; i<a.length; ++i)
    c[i] = new Point3f(a[i]);

for (int i=0; i<b.length; ++i)
    c[i+a.length] = new Point3f(b[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you got fancy with your `++` operators. Instead of `c[i++]` you should use `c[i+1]`.

The expression `var++` adds `1` to `var`, and leaves it there. Your `c[i++]` access *different* array elements, and then you've got `i += 2` in the loop header to advance your index even further from where it should be.

```
c[i+1].x = b[j].getX();
c[i+1].y = b[j].getY();
c[i+1].z = b[j].getZ();

// Debugging
System.out.println(i+"\t"+j+"\t"+c[i]+"\t"+a[j]+"\t"+c[i+1]+"\t"+b[j]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've changed that but I'm still getting null pointer though :(

Comment: @Eugene Check that you are passing non-null values for `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at how your `i` changes through each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are making this too complicated

1. Create the new array (you are calculating size right)
2. Then do a loop and add all elements from the first array
3. Then another loop to add the elements from the second array (make sure to offset for the elements already added from array1)